# Work on a segment of the database

Tags: mysql, segment

I have a `MySQL` database which is used by many registered users. 
I have a stored procedure comprising of about 50 statements.
For each statement, I have to add the clause `"WHERE USER_ID = 123"` to make sure that they act only on the login users.

I tried to create a VIEW with the clause `"WHERE USER_ID = parameter"` but `MySQL` does not accept the parameter.

Is there a short cut to avoid having to write the `"WHERE"` clause in 50 statements, as there is the risk that it may behave wrongly and work on the data belonging to other users?

Comment: Are all those statements addressing the same table? What does "MySQL does not accept the parameter" mean? It's maybe a good idea to post the whole procedure.

Comment: It addresses various tables all of which have the user_id as a field.